# Subdomains not working when www is added?

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have purchased My Domain name from one registrar & hosted in another hosting company.
I have created a sub domain from my hosting domain manager lie `http://subdomain.domain.com` and it works fine. But when someone types in `www.subdomain.domain.com` the site is not working.

Do I need to make changes in my DNS Manager of hosting CPanel or DNS Manager of my Domain CPanel?

Also What all Records I need to add ( like A Record or CNAME) to redirect `www.subdomain.domain.com` to `subdomain.domain.com`.

I don't want to see `www` for my subdomain, but only wants to get redirected to `subdomain.domain.com`.

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't work because www.subdomain.domain.com doesn't exist. You have to add a CNAME record in your zone subdomain.domain.com the same way you've added the host subdomain to domain.com.

Comment: when some people type www.subdomain.domain.com it should go to subdomain.domain.com . How to achieve this redirection?

Comment: The first thing to do is to add a CNAME record to `subdomain.domain.com` for the host `www` in the zone `subdomain.domain.com`. Secondly, you can add a redirection in your webserver configuration for every request on the host `www`. (for Apache, http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/redirect-domain-www-subdomain.shtml it seems to answer the question)

Comment: It looks right. You can just check it by resolving `www.fish-warrior.***.com` in a console with a tool such as `dig`. You now need to configure your webserver.

Comment: Do I need to add a A Record like www.fish-warrior.*****.com which points to the IP? And how to configure the web server?

Comment: No, a CNAME record is a better id while `www.fish-warrior.***.com` will always point to the same IP as `fish-warrior.***.com`. The webserver configuration depends on what you use. I gave you a link for Apache above, for others like nginx, finding tutorial for redirection is easy.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.fish-warrior.fugenx\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://fish-warrior.fugenx.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L] - My htaccess. Also is there anything I Need to do in my hosting Account

Answer (score 11):

You need to register that subdomin too.

Yes - `www.subdomain.domain.com` is a subdomin of `subdomain.domain.com`. There is nothing special about the `www` prefix, as far as the domain system or browsers are concerned.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me out. I hope it helps anyone going through the same thing.

> Yes, as you said CNAME record www for customer1.mysite.com will report an error.
>   To make it working, you should be able to add CNAME record www.customer1 for mysite.com instead of www for customer1.mysite.com - xMudrii https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-configure-subdomains-to-use-www-and-non-www

Answer (score 0):

Create `CNAME` as `sub.domain`.

Point to `@` where `sub.domain` is your `subdomain` name and `maindomain` name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add "www" in the subdomain then create the same configuration subdomain and add "www" in that domain.

you required to add both domains name **[www.subdomain.domain.com](http://www.subdomain.domain.com)** and **subdomain.domain.com**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a website `www.example.com` and you want to have a working link like `www.service.example.com`, then you need to enter the subdomain name `www.service` (and not `service`) while setting up the sub-domain.

Preferably set up both sub-domains i.e. `www.service` and `service` for users who type in `www.service.example.com` and `service.example.com` on their browsers.