# nginx DNS works for http:// but NOT for www. Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server

Hi I'm pretty new to servers so I'm following the [digital ocean guides](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) of setting it up from 0 to node.js.
(somestring replaces the actual first part of the url here just to be safe.)

I have added my url to /etc/nginx/sites-available/somestring.online-server.cloud/html

and this as the content:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/somestring.online-server.cloud/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name somestring.online-server.cloud www.somestring.online-server.cloud;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

the first url works with http://somestring.online-server.cloud but the second with www does not resolve. this throws errors so i'd like to fix it.
Could this be a limitation of the hosting provider (ionos / 1&1), or did i miss something?

Oddly enough there is a question that is the exact opposite where www works but http doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check these answers, It should help

[Subdomains not working when www is added?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296054/subdomains-not-working-when-www-is-added?rq=1)

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-configure-subdomains-to-use-www-and-non-www

Comment: cheers for the response! I ended up just removing the www version since i didn't need it anyway